# Assign static public IP to LB in Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

My workflow is something on the lines of:

1. Create a static Public IP on Azure and map it to a DNS name.
2. Then start a service in Kubernetes which spins up a an LB to which we attached the pre-reserved public IP.

Approach 1:

```
externalName: <FQDN>
```

Approach 2:

```
type: LoadBalancer
externalIPs:
- 52.232.30.160
```

Approach 3:

```
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: 52.232.30.160
```

Approach 4:

```
type: LoadBalancer
clusterIP: 52.166.121.161
```

But none of them seems to work. The LB always gets 2 public IPs - one statically assigned and the other dynamically assigned.

I was wondering what is the right way to do this and if Azure supports assignment of public IPs to the LB.

Comment: have you try to use CLI command `kubectl expose --external-ip=`?

Comment: @krish7919 Is your static public IP present in the public IPs of LB? If so, hitting that IP will send the traffic to LB and that should forward the traffic to your pods.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
  name: my-nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: $clusterip
  loadBalancerIP: $externalip
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

available external addresses check in fronted ip configuration of azure load balancer (but not masters)

Comment: hi, what should I set in clusterIp and loadBalancerIp?

Comment: ip address that you want to set